# CURL example to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to convert curl command to powershell Invoke-RestMethod

Command from MobileIron (in case someone will google that topic)

```
curl --user <username>:<password> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request PUT 'https://
<mobileiron_core>/api/v2/devices/wakeup?adminDeviceSpaceId=1' --data '{"deviceUuids": ["af0cea8bf56c-
49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"], "note": "something"}'
```

Ok, my code (based on https://gist.github.com/rayterrill/e83a1bd877547eccfd59b656e7f91b48#file-mobileiron-addremovelabels-ps1 )

```
$url = $mi_server + "/api/v2/devices/wakeup?adminDeviceSpaceId=1"
$contentType = "application/json"      

$headers = @{
    Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $regase64AuthInfo)
}

$data = @{        
    note = "test";
    deviceUuids = $guid
};

$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json;
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Body $data;
```

But i am getting 400 error - so,as i understand - something wrong with --data , but what ?

Comment: You're converting `$data` to JSON but not using it. Change `-Body $data` to `-Body $json`

Comment: @Avshalom When a PUT request is made, the -data and the -Body is ignored.  A PUT transfers data via a query string appended to the URL.  Only on POST can JSON be transferred  in the POST Request Body and ONLY if the Content-Type is application/json .  In a PUT Request the Response Server will only see the Query String.   JSON should not be used in the Query String.

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke-RestMethod` rather than curl?   All MobileIron's documentation is for curl.

Comment: well, because almost all company servers are on windows

Comment: Windows 10 / Windows Server 2019 and above now come with `curl.exe`  (and `tar.exe`), so you can use existing `curl` commands (small adjustments for PowerShell's syntax may be needed) - just make sure you specify the executable as `curl.exe`, not just `curl`, because the latter is a built-in _alias_ for `Invoke-WebRequest` in Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

MobileIron 400 is a general error: 400 Bad request, Meaning the request was invalid.
The accompanying error message (That follows the the error code) explains the reason.
Can you post the rest of the error message?
You cannot use `--data` or `-Body` with a `PUT` request.

You must make a query string for the data. 
The query string must be url encoded.

Because it is HTTPS transfer you may need -k (--insecure)

The PUT request may work, I believe MobileIron  prefers GET, There is no real difference between the two.  I tested both.

I tried (I did my testing with PHP)
A PUT Request
Request Headers

```
 Content-Type: application/json
 Accept: application/json
```

POST DATA was the same as the Query String
I checked with and without the POST DATA and no change.
I also sent the POST DATA with no query string and it was if not data was sent.

URL and Query

```
 $query = urlencode('{"deviceUuids": ["af0cea8bf56c-49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"], "note": "something"}');
 $url =  https://<domain>/api/v2/devices/wakeup? . $query
```

URL was changed to my server to an app that returns the request header, and parameters. 
Which returned this on the server:
Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Expect: 100-continue
Host: mydomain.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The server GET and server REQUEST values

```
$_GET
array (
  '{"deviceUuids":_' => 
  array (
    '"af0cea8bf56c-49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"' => '',
  ),
)
$_REQUEST
array (
  '{"deviceUuids":_' => 
  array (
    '"af0cea8bf56c-49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"' => '',
  ),
)
```

The Request Query

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])  (url decoded)
{"deviceUuids": ["af0cea8bf56c-49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"], "note": "something"}
```

Notice above the JSON query string was cut off.
But was in the arguments

```
argv array (url decoded)    
0 = {"deviceUuids":
1 = ["af0cea8bf56c-49f5-b615-76cc34936b2f"],
2 = "note":
3 = "something"}
```

I removed the Content-Type: application/json from the request header and there was no change.
I changed the PUT to GET, no change 
When a I started sending the `Content=Type: application/json`
With a POST request, and no Query String, the POS Data was ONLY in the BODY of the request.

And here are some example requesst from some MobileIron documentation:
The first request was a default GET not a PUT.

```
curl -u admin_username:admin_password -kv "https://URL_to_your_mobileiron_cloud_environment/api/v1/account?emailAddress=johnnydoe@acme.com&uid=johnnydoe@acme.com&accountSource=Local" -d ''

curl GET -kv -u user:password "https://[mobileiron_cloud]/api/v1/device/57d9903c-aadf-4b40-aef3-e1f24302f180/customattributes”

curl -X POST -kv -u user:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "attrs" : { "tlark" : [ "1" ] } } ' "https://[mobileiron_cloud]/api/v1/device/22000/customattributes"

curl -X POST -kv -u user:password -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "attrs" : { "tlark" : [ "1" ] } } ' "https://[mobileiron_cloud]/api/v1/device/8bcc4cee-dca9-476d-8710-9bb1e738ade9/customattributes"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   $param_pam_pam = @{
        Method      = 'PUT'
        Uri         = "$url"
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Headers     = @{authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $regase64AuthInfo) }
        Body        = @{
                        deviceUuids = @($guid)
                        note = "force check-in from $ma"
                        } | ConvertTo-Json
    }

    $reg = Invoke-RestMethod @param_pam_pam
```